# Trying to skip a row in CSV file when detected row is "N/A" or "\0" in C++

Tags: c++

I have tried to use this if(temp =="N/A" || temp=="\0") function but i keep getting error of terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
what():  stoi

```
istream & operator >>(istream & input, wLogVec & data) //overloaded input string op
{
    WindLog windLog;
    string line;
    int count = 0;
    while(getline(input, line))
    {
        if(count!=0)
        {
            stringstream ss(line);
            string temp;
            Date date;
            Time time;

            ss >> date >> time;
            for(int i=0; i<9; i++) //skip unnecessary columns
            {
                getline(ss, temp, ',');
            }
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            if(temp =="N/A" || temp=="\0")
            {
                continue;
            }
            float speed = stof(temp);
            getline(ss, temp, ',');
            float solRad = (stof(temp));
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++) //skip unnecessary columns
            {
                getline(ss, temp, ',');
            }
            getline(ss, temp);
            float airTemp = stof(temp);
            //Add new WindLog object with parameters into wLogVec vector

            data.Add(new WindLog(date, time, speed, solRad, airTemp));
        }
        count++;
    }
    return input;
}
```

my data is as below:
[image]

The code will take in input from certain columns, it will work when I manually delete the empty row in csv but it wouldn't work when there is a N/A value or an empty row.

Comment: I'd guess `temp=="\0"` should just be `temp.empty()`

Comment: Why would you just not loop with a single `while (getline(input, line)) {... }` and check `if (line.empty())` to handle the empty line? There is no need for multiple reads with `getline()` within the read-loop.

Answer (score 0):

As Alan Birtles mentioned, you should check for an empty value using `temp.empty` instead of `temp == "\0"` (which would be better written as `'\0'`, but I don't think it makes a difference, please correct me if it does). Basically, `'\0'` does not mean the string is empty, `'\0'` *is* a character itself, the first one in the ASCII table.

I made a test in an excel worksheet with random numbers that I exported as a csv file. This was the output:

```
79667,7,484,48,76,87689,7698,5643,643,537,4,7854,754
887657,4,8754,574,764,675,685,876,87,575,65,876,5
,,,,,,,,,,,,
87,9687,678,5687,55,344,364,3735,7635,3765,365,48,74
```

Notice how the second line is just a lot of commas. That's because there are no characters between the commas. If there actually were `'\0'` (null-terminator) characters, the file would look like this:

```
79667,7,484,48,76,87689,7698,5643,643,537,4,7854,754
887657,4,8754,574,764,675,685,876,87,575,65,876,5
, , , , , , , , , , , ,
87,9687,678,5687,55,344,364,3735,7635,3765,365,48,74
```

If opened with a hex viewer, you can actually see the `'\0'` characters: [I used HxD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovbBx.png)

So, to sum up, you don't check for `'\0'` characters, but rather for empty strings with `test.empty()`.